# Youtube replay not working in flash player 10.3.183.5

Tags: flash, youtube

Since upgrading to flash player 10.3.183.5, whenever I watch a video on youtube and then click "replay", it reloads the entire video from youtube's website. My internet connection is quite slow and previous versions of flash would replay the video from memory/cache instead of re-downloading it.

Is this a known issue with this version of flash player? Is there a setting I could change to enable the cacheing of videos? Or is the problem with youtube themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running the latest version of flash and dont have any issues...

but try this:

Go to youtube and play a video.  right click on the video and go to settings.  click on the third tab (at the bottom) for local storage settings.  You can adjust the slider.  Going all the way to the right enables unlimited storage.